# Does PHP performance increase by disabling modules?

Tags: php, linux, apache, performance, configuration

I'm running PHP 7.1.10 with Apache 2.4.6. There's a bunch of PHP modules that are probably not used in my application. Is there any performance boost disabling them?

```
# ls /etc/php.d
10-opcache.ini   20-dom.ini       20-gettext.ini  20-mbstring.ini  20-shmop.ini      20-sysvsem.ini    20-xsl.ini         30-wddx.ini
20-bz2.ini       20-exif.ini      20-gmp.ini      20-mysqlnd.ini   20-simplexml.ini  20-sysvshm.ini    20-zip.ini         30-xmlreader.ini
20-calendar.ini  20-fileinfo.ini  20-iconv.ini    20-pdo.ini       20-sockets.ini    20-tokenizer.ini  30-mysqli.ini      opcache-default.blacklist
20-ctype.ini     20-ftp.ini       20-imap.ini     20-phar.ini      20-sqlite3.ini    20-xml.ini        30-pdo_mysql.ini
20-curl.ini      20-gd.ini        20-json.ini     20-posix.ini     20-sysvmsg.ini    20-xmlwriter.ini  30-pdo_sqlite.ini
```

Example, 20-posix.ini:

```
# cat /etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
; Enable posix extension module
extension=posix.so
```

Can I safely disable most modules, or is there no significant performance boost?

Comment: I don’t use php that often anymore only for some legacy scripts so I don’t know if this is still the case, but you should check if removing those modules does decrease the memory usage of each apache or php-fpm instance. If the memory usage decreases then it is definitely a good idea to disable those modules.

Answer (score 1):

Usually core extensions does not have real impact on performances. But some knowns extensions are really performances-killing like Xdebug (which should be strictly reserved to dev environment).

However if you plan to not make use of some specific extensions you can still make a quick benchmark to test if there's a notable performances changes.

But to be honest as of php7, they highly improved performances by removing old and greedy code, unsupported SAPI, etc. So you should not be worried at all about that.